# Why do conditional formatting rules based on date affect the wrong cells?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Here is a Google Sheet for our church rota - publicly viewable: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KODl9N_I3VeO0CKBrU_75GoQ5dBvUuSzx0FinNKf9zs/edit?usp=sharing

I have conditional formatting rules applied to the whole range:

1. `=countIF($A1,"<"&TODAY())` - set grey background for rows already happened
2. `=COUNTIFS($A1,">"&TODAY(),$A1,"<"&TODAY()+10)` - highlight the upcoming week or two

Yet today is January 4th 2023, and it is greying out the row Jan 15, and *not* rows above that. And the upcoming weeks are 8 & 15 Jan, yet the week 22nd Jan is the one being highlighted.

[image]

It was previously working but whenever people make edits, this sort of problem happens - it seems very fragile but worse, I can't even see *why* it's wrong. I can't see additional conditional formatting rules, it all looks right to me but I cannot fix it or see why it's not working as expected.

Comment: is it because the dates after the first date in A3 are derived from formulas rather than actual dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules (*apply to range A3:C*):

**grey**     `=$A3<today()`

**yellow**    `=and($A3>=today(),$A3<today()+10)`

Comment: It would improve your answer if you explained why this works.